# Why FormCalc gives zero amplitude for this process

Tags: packages, feyncalc

Why when I generate self energy diagram of for neutrinos, FormCalc gives zero amplitude ? here is the code

```
t12 := CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 1, ExcludeTopologies -> Internal]
ins := InsertFields[t12, F[1, {3}] -> F[1, {3}]];

amp = CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins]]
```

which gives zero amplitude:

```
Amp[{{F[1, {3}], k[1], 0, {0, LeptonNumber}}} -> {{F[1, {3}], k[2], 
     0, {0, LeptonNumber}}}][0]
```

It's known that neutrino is massless in SM (the default choice of FA) but painting [ins] gives diagrams mediated by W and Z bosons as in the next figure, so why their amplitudes have not evaluated ?

[image]

Comment: FeynCalc is actively maintained by Shtabovenko. You may find it helpful to browse and ask your question on the [FeynCalc forum](http://www.feyncalc.org/forum/).

Comment: OP clearly confuses FeynCalc and FormCalc here, see also [this link](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/FAQ#fcfc) CalcFeynAmp is a FormCalc function and has nothing to do with FeynCalc. So the title should be edited to "Why **FormCalc** ...". I've already suggested him to contact Thomas Hahn (developer of FormCalc) directly, since afaik there are no FormCalc experts around on this site.

Comment: I changed the question title anyway .. thanx

Comment: @vsht I think the description for the [tag:feyncalc] tag serves to exacerbate the confusion -- it probably should be changed ASAP.

Comment: @QuantumDot Do you propose to introduce a separate tag for every HEP package: `FeynArts`, `FormCalc`, `FeynCalc`, `LoopTools`, `FeynRules` etc.? BTW, I was not the one who created this tag and started to add it to questions that were not related to `FeynCalc`. The description merely reflects the current usage of the tag.

Comment: @vsht Probably best to rename the whole tag to "High Energy Physics" or "HEP" or something like that.  I didn't mean to blame you for the tag; instead I just wanted to let you know about this possible source of confusion.

Comment: @QuantumDot "HEP" sounds good. I clearly don't have enough privileges to rename a tag, but it would be nice if someone senior here could do it. I did not mean to be or to sound offended, it is just that after following the discussion on meta I realized that there is no firm policy about questions to third-party packages on this site, so it is not so clear what to do in such cases.

Comment: Hay @vsht. Can you tell me why did we use here `Truncated` , since i'm not expert in FormCalc, isn't enough to use only `OnShell-> False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have nothing to do with `FormCalc`, I think that I understand what is the problem here: Since you want to compute self-energy, you need to use the option `Truncated` when generating the amplitudes. Otherwise the amplitude is generated with external spinors and vanishes because of the equation of motion (Dirac equation). The correct code reads:

```
<< FormCalc`FormCalc`
<< FeynArts`FeynArts`

$FAVerbose = 0;
t12 = CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 1, ExcludeTopologies -> Internal];
ins = InsertFields[t12, F[1, {3}] -> F[1, {3}], 
   InsertionLevel -> {Particles}];
Paint[ins, ColumnsXRows -> {3, 1}, ImageSize -> {768, 256}];

CalcFeynAmp[CreateFeynAmp[ins, Truncated -> True], OnShell -> False]
```

and the result is

```
Amp[{{F[1, {3}], k[1], 0, {0, LeptonNumber}}} -> {{F[1, {3}], k[2], 
     0, {0, LeptonNumber}}}][-(1/(\[Pi] SW2))
  Alfa (1/16 (2 + 1/CW2) Finite + 1/8 (B0i[bb1, Pair[k[1], k[1]], 0, MZ2]/
        CW2 + (2 + ML2/MW2) B0i[bb1, Pair[k[1], k[1]], ML2, MW2])) GA[6, k[1]]]
```

To see why the amplitude is zero without `Truncated->True` one can use the following FeynCalc code

```
$LoadFeynArts = True;
<< FeynCalc`

$FAVerbose = 0;
t12 = CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 1, ExcludeTopologies -> Internal];
ins = InsertFields[t12, F[1, {3}] -> F[1, {3}], InsertionLevel -> {Particles}];
amp1 = FCFAConvert[CreateFeynAmp[ins], IncomingMomenta -> {p}, 
    OutgoingMomenta -> {p}, LoopMomenta -> {q}, SMP -> True, List -> False] // Contract;
amp2 = amp1 // TID[#, q] & // ToPaVe[#, q] & //Collect2[#, DOT, IsolateNames -> KK] &
```

Here we simplify the Dirac algebra and perform 1-loop tensor decomposition. After that we collect terms w.r.t to the remaining Dirac structures and introduce abbreviations to make the result better readable. What we get is

$$
\frac{1}{128} \text{KK}(103) (\varphi (p)).(\gamma \cdot p).\bar{\gamma }^7.(\varphi (p)),
$$

where $\bar{\gamma }^7$ is the usual left handed projector. The resulting expression is zero by Dirac equation, since neutrinos are massless in the SM model of FeynArts. We can also see this in FeynCalc by evaluating

```
amp2 // DiracSimplify
```

which gives zero.

Comment: Hay @vsht .. actually now the amplitude does not go to zero but when I continue squaring  `amp` and using `LoopTools` I can't get numerical results .. if you have an idea about that, can you look at my code in this post  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128074/now-why-looptools-do-not-make-calculation  .. thanx